# Cauchy's functional multiplicative equation on the unit interval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

This question might be trivial, but I didn't find a clean reference and have not attempted to prove it myself yet: Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous and monotonic function such that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, and for every $x,y\in [0,1]$, $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$, can we conclude that $f(x)=x^a$ for some $a$? In other words, is the standard solution robust to replacing the domain of real numbers with the unit interval? If not, what other conditions on $f$ guarantee the standard solution? Could you give me some references in either case? I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Indeed, let $x_*:=\sup E$, where $E:=\{x\in[0,1]\colon f(x)=0\}$. We have $0\in E$, so that $E\ne\emptyset$. Also, $x_*\in E$, because $f$ is continuous and hence $E$ is closed. So, $f(x_*)=0$. Also, $x_*<1$, since $f(1)=1\ne0$. So, if $x_*>0$, then for all small enough $h>0$ we have $f(x_*+h)>0$ and $f(\frac{x_*}{x_*+h})>0$, whence $0=f(x_*)=f(x_*+h)f(\frac{x_*}{x_*+h})>0$, a contradiction.

So, $x_*=0$, that is, $f>0$ on $(0,1]$. Letting now
$$g(u):=-\ln f(e^{-u})$$
for $u\in[0,\infty)$, we get
$$g(u+v)=g(u)+g(v)$$
for $u$ and $v$ in $[0,\infty)$, so that $g(u)=cu$ for some real $c$ and all $u\in[0,\infty)$ -- see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Properties_of_nonlinear_solutions_over_the_real_numbers).
So, $f(x)=x^c$ for all $x\in(0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous and $f(0)=0$, we have $c>0$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: +1. You beat me to it.  However, the solution for $h(u+v) = h(u)+h(v)$ for $u,v \ge 0$ needs reference.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : Thank you for your comment and for the +1. I have added a reference to the Cauchy functional equation.

Comment: My approach was to extend $h$ to all of $\mathbb R$, then cite a reference for the usual Cauchy equation.

Comment: Minor remark: Instead of taking 'small enough $h$' you could take the square root of $x_*$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : Thank you for your comment. That would be a bit simpler, indeed.

Comment: Thank you so much, both!

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous, we can consider
\begin{align*}
F(x)&=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt = x\int_0^1 f(sx)\, ds = xf(x)\int_0^1 f(s)\, ds \\
& = Cxf(x) =CxF'(x) ,
\end{align*}
with $C=F(1)>0$. The solution of this ODE with $F(1)=C$ is $F=Cx^{1/C}$, so $f=x^{-1+1/C}$, as desired. (Of course, it is well known that Cauchy's functional equation becomes trivial once one is allowed to differentiate.)

The continuity (or monotonicity) of $f$ was not really needed. The calculation also works when $f\in L^1$.

Comment: When $f \in L^1$ we get $F(x) = CxF'(x)$ only almost everywhere, I guess.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Yes, but that's fine, since ODEs for absolutely continuous functions have the same basic theory.

Comment: But our conclusion is supposed to be $f(x) = x^a$ everywhere.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: This does follow since in fact $f=F/(Cx)\in AC((0,1])$. I just have to reorganize the last part slightly (differentiate the original functional equation, which is in fact exactly what I did in an earlier version).